# What is the easiest way to learn notation?

Tags: guitar, theory, piano, notation, sheet-music

I am a self-taught guitar player. I don't know most of the music theory and techniques. Whenever I compose a tune, I record it in my phone. Now I want to share it with the professional pianist but I don't know how to write them into notation.

Is there any easy way to learn notation, so that I can learn and practice it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guitar-specific way is to use [**Guitar Pro**](https://www.guitar-pro.com/en/index.php). In the program, you can write tablature (or even click on the frets you want) and the program automatically turns them into standard notes.

The layout is pretty simple:

[image]

You type the fret number on the **TAB** section and the respective note appears on the clef:[image]

And this is the fretboard that you can click on:

[image]

Besides that, a way to learn the notation is, probably the most common way, by reading (and singing) solfege.

Comment: This is a good way to *write* notation, however the question asks about *learning* how to write notation.

Comment: @Tim It's a way to learn. You can see how each note is represented on the staff

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no. Notation consists of timing and pitch, both of which are contained in the 'dots'. Keys, signatures, etc. have to be learned, and it's a fairly lengthy process. But - worth learning, as it's a great way to communicate your music to other musos. Start with simple tunes, play them (in C initially), and follow some of the many offerings googlable which explain how to write what you play and hear. Or find a teacher, at least in the early stages. Your pianist may well be able to help here.

Another way is to play it into certain software, which then translates it into music, which can be printed out in a form for the pianist to read.

Tab isn't going to help, as the same note can be portrayed in several different places, often there's no timing, and the pianist probably wouldn't be able to read it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to learn notation is to be in a musical situation where you NEED to play from notation.  As a lone guitarist, you may have to manufacture this situation.  Get some 'fake books' with the melody notated, make it a project to read and play a couple of new songs every day.  You'll probably need some help.

Comment: Certainly will need some help with the fake book tunes. Hardly a starter level!

Comment: But it's a REAL project.  He'll respond much better than to 'A B C' exercises.